# Negel vasser on a plane

Tags: halacha, travel, netilat-yadayim-washing

I've been on planes where the only sink available is in the toilet. What would be the best thing to do in regards to negel vasser/netilas yodayim?

Edit: The toilet is a mokom tumah. Furthermore, the Lubavitcher Rebbe once told someone (I don't recall who) not to take water from there to use for negel vasser.

Comment: similar http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3396/759

Comment: "The toilet is a mokom tumah" perhaps edit this to clarify. I doubt you refer to tum'at met, or to some other formal tum'ah. Perhaps clarify that your mean general "badness" (if that is what you mean).

Comment: @mevaqesh I can find the source in Shu"a. You can't say daven, say brochos etc

Comment: I think you can take water from there and even wash your hands there. Also todays conveniences are clean,  similar to what  are called persian ones, although not exactly the same,  and dont necessarily  have the din of mokom tomai.

Comment: Why do you think the toliet is a "makom tumah" or a place where a person wouldn't be able to wash their hands. The type of toliet in the plane flushes the waste away completely to a different area. It should seemingly be like our modern day toliets which many poskim say doesn't have a din of a "beis hacisa" l'inyan "tumah".

Comment: Yes but unlike the "persian" ones they dont do it "straight"  away. @Yehoshua.

Answer (score 3):

הרב רצון ערוסי [paskens](http://shut.moreshet.co.il/shut2.asp?id=163275) that

א. מותר ליטול בבית הכסא רק את הברכה יברך מחוץ לבית הכסא. יהיה בית הכסא אשר יהיה. 
ב. בית הכסא (מודרני) של ימינו (אסלה ומי ניקוז וכיסוי לאסלה), מותר לברך מחוצה לו, ואפילו כנגדו, אך לא בתוכו.

1) You can wash your hands in a modern toilet but must say the berocho outside

2) One may make a berocho outside a modern toilet (with toilet drain and toilet cover) even opposite it but not inside.

The [Rav's bio](http://shut.moreshet.co.il/advancedSearchResult.asp?i=0&nop=20&WholeWord=0&rabonim=10448&x=7&y=6) reads in part:
He is the Rav of Kiryat Ono and a member of Israel's Chief Rabbinate Council.

Answer (score 2):

I once saw somebody on a plane do *netilat yadayim* at his seat.  He had carried a bottle of water onto the plane and used small amounts of it over a plastic cup.  (I don't know if he brought the cup on or if he got it from an attendant.)  I didn't ask him about it, so I don't know his sources or tradition.

While in some locations, including the US, you can't carry a bottle of water through airport security, you *can* either carry an empty bottle and fill it from a drinking fountain on the other side or purchase a bottle after going through security.

Comment: Sounds good, although a cup is a bit small to pour into. Maybe if you pour into a bag with no holes, like a vomit bag which is easy to close. Also, bottles are often supplied on the plane. I once heard that bottles with narrow openings are problematic, though I have no idea why nor a source.

Comment: Usually you can carry up to 100ml but on any plane I've been on, especially if it's a long enough journey, they have water available to drink (and you could wash with it).

Comment: @user613 it was one of those short, wide cups, like the ones the airlines use when they serve drinks.  The bigger challenge might be disposing of the now-full cup; I didn't notice what he did with it.